# ArrayList readLines

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

whats wrong with this code? help please

```
 val filesDir = filesDir
 val todoFile = File(filesDir, "todo.txt")
 items = ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile))
```

//PS: FileUtils is from (implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2')

this is the error:

```
(40, 21): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments 
supplied:
public final fun <E> <init>(p0: (MutableCollection<out 
String!>..Collection<String!>?)): kotlin.collections.ArrayList<String> /* = 
java.util.ArrayList<String> */ defined in kotlin.collections.ArrayList
public final fun <E> <init>(p0: Int): kotlin.collections.ArrayList<String> /* 
= java.util.ArrayList<String> */ defined in kotlin.collections.ArrayList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readLines` in this version of `FileUtils` returns `List`, but Kotlin expects `List<String>` in `ArrayList<String>` constructor. You can cast the result like:

```
items = ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile) as List<String>)
```

(but you will get a warning of unchecked cast here), or you can use newer library version, where function is defined to return `List<String>`.